# Get start and end date by month name, not month number

Tags: sql-server

How do I get **start date** and **end date** of a month by month name? Not by date, not by month number.

For example, this gets me first day of current month. Input is a date type, not string like I want it to be.

```
SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

What I want is to input month name in string like 'March' not 3 and get 2016/03/01 and 2016/03/31. I'd really be overwhelmed and appreciate any/all help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a CTE to get the month number:

```
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(10) = 'March';

WITH CteMonths(n, m) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'January' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'February' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'March' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'April' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'May' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'June' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'July' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'August' UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 'September' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 'October' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 'November' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 'December'
)
SELECT
    DATEADD(MONTH, n - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)),
    DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
FROM CteMonths
WHERE m = @month
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Can I use CTE in some table column like UDFs are used?

Comment: Depends, you may put it in a function. Use iTVF for performance.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I will try it out in a little while and get back to you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502708/get-attendance-by-month-name