# Get attendance by month name

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find attendance for any month like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE
SET @StartDate = '2016/10/01'
SET @EndDate = '2016/10/31'


SELECT
StaffAttendance.StaffId, DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) AS [ForMonth],
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 1)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalWorkingDays,
  SUM(StaffAttendance.AttendanceStatusId) AS TotalDaysWorked FROM StaffAttendance WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND StaffAttendance.AttendanceStatusId = 1 GROUP BY StaffAttendance.StaffId
```

And this is what I am getting, which is just fine.

[image]

What I want to do next is omit the date range (@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE) and use month name instead like - 'October' and not month number like '10.' So that user gives a month name and start and end dates for that month are automatically calculated. I got help for that by Felix Pamittan.

```
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(9) = 'february';

WITH CteMonths(n, m) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'January' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'February' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'March' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'April' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'May' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'June' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'July' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'August' UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 'September' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 'October' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 'November' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 'December'
)
SELECT
    DATEADD(MONTH, n - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS StartDate,
    DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0))) AS EndDate
FROM CteMonths
WHERE m = @month
```

Now, how do I combine these two and get same result as above?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(9) = 'february';

WITH CteMonths(n, m) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'January' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'February' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'March' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'April' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'May' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'June' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'July' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'August' UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 'September' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 'October' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 'November' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 'December'
)
SELECT
    sa.StaffId, 
    DATENAME(MONTH, t.StartDate) AS [ForMonth],
    (DATEDIFF(dd, t.StartDate, t.EndDate) + 1)
        - (DATEDIFF(wk, t.StartDate, t.EndDate) * 1)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, t.StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalWorkingDays,
    SUM(sa.AttendanceStatusId) AS TotalDaysWorked 
FROM StaffAttendance sa
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(MONTH, n - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS StartDate,
        DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0))) AS EndDate
    FROM CteMonths
) t
WHERE 
    sa.[Date] >= t.StartDate
    AND sa.[Date] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, t.EndDate)
    AND sa.AttendanceStatusId = 1 
GROUP BY sa.StaffId
```